# Setting bits & verifying using hex values (C)

Tags: c

In one byte i set some bits
|Video | Audio | speaker | mic | Headphone | Led  with bits
|1     | 1     | 1       |  3  | 1         | 1
1 byte for all except for mic which has 3 bytes and thus can have 7 combination leaving
the first combination.

```
#define Video    0x01
#define Audio    0x02
#define Speaker     0x04
#define MicType1  0x08 
#define MicType2  0x10
#define MicType3  0x20
#define MicType4 (0x08 | 0x10) 
#define MicType5 (0x08 | 0x20)
#define MicType6 (0x10 | 0x20)
#define MicType7 ((0x08 | 0x10) | 0x20)
#define HeadPhone 0x40
#define Led    0x80
```

Now I set the bits

```
MySpecs[2] |= (1 << 0);
MySpecs[2] |= (1 << 2);
```

//set mictype6

```
MySpecs[2] |= (1 << 4);
MySpecs[2] |= (1 << 5);
```

when I do read like this

```
 readCamSpecs()
    {
        if(data[0] &  Video)
            printf("device with Video\n");
        else
            printf("device with no Video\n");
        if(data[0] & Audio) 
            printf("device with Audio\n");
        else
            printf("device with no Audio\n");

        if(data[0] & Mictype7)
            printf("device with Mictype7\n");
        if(data[0] & Mictype6)
            printf("device with Mictype6\n");
    }
```

The values set with single bits, it can find.
But the values set with multiple bits (e.g, MicType5,6,7) it makes error
and displays whatever is the first in check.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Upvote the author - he is too low to upvote useful answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `&` check succeeds even when there's only one bit set, as the result would still be non-zero.

Try `if ( data[0] & Mictype7 == MicType7 )` instead.

Comment: worked like a charm. Only one has to put extra brackets otherwise it
will start comparing from left to right. This works for my compiler
if ( (data[0] & Mictype7) == MicType7 ).
P.S. And what a forum. Thanks all. and Sorry can't upvote you, got not enough guineas.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#define MicTypeMask (0x08 | 0x10 | 0x20)


if((data[0] & MicTypeMask) == Mictype7)
    printf("device with Mictype7\n");
if((data[0] & MicTypeMask) == Mictype6)
    printf("device with Mictype6\n");

if((data[0] & MicTypeMask) == 0)
    printf("device without Mic\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

`data[0] & Mictype7` will evaluate to true if the result is not 0, i.e. if either of 3 bits are set. The following will match MicType7 precisely:
`if(data[0] & Mictype7 == Mictype7)`

Try this out to see the concept:
`if (Mictype7 & Mictype6) printf("Oh what is it?!!");`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remove the else parts. Because unnecessarily it prints error messages.

```
 readCamSpecs()
    {            
        if(!data[0])
            printf("Print your error message stating nothing is connected. \n");

        if(data[0] &  Video)
            printf("device with Video\n");

        if(data[0] & Audio) 
            printf("device with Audio\n");

        if(data[0] & Mictype7)
            printf("device with Mictype7\n");

        if(data[0] & Mictype6)
            printf("device with Mictype6\n");    
    }
```